# gdal_polygonize.py - Silly Size requested

Tags: geotiff-tiff

While running this:

```
./gdal_polygonize.py GBSM_JKR_ALL_WGS_GEOREFERENCED.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" to_shapefile/
```

When the process memory size reaches 32GB it dies with:

```
ERROR 1: CPLRealloc(-6442451024): Silly size requested.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I am trying to convert this file to a shapefile to load it into a database. The .tif file is 101gb. The machine has 3TB of memory. I am (very!) new to GIS systems and have been googling each error.

Is it possible to

1. run this to exceed a 32gb memory allocation?
2. chop up the .tif file so that it can be converted piecemeal?

Comment: You will for sure hit the 2 GB/4 GB size limit of shapefile so your command will fail in any case. I feel also that your plan to polygonize so big image with gdal_polygonize is not good even if you used some better format for output. I suggest to study PostGIS raster instead http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_reference.html.